# Quick way of checking if a 2D array contains an element c#

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I'm currently coding battleships as a part of a college project. The game works perfectly fine but I'd like to implement a way to check if a ship has been completely sunk. This is the method I'm currently using:

```
public static bool CheckShipSunk(string[,] board, string ship){
    for(int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++){
            if(board[i,j] == ship){return false;}
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The problem with this is that there are 5 ships, and this is very inefficient when checking hundreds of elements 5 times over, not to mention the sub-par quality of college computers. Is there an easier way of checking if a 2D array contains an element?

Comment: Instead of iterating through the entire board and checking every cell, you can keep track of the number of cells containing the ship. Then, once you have hit a cell containing the ship, you decrement the count. When the count reaches zero, you know that the ship has been completely sunk.

Comment: I would get width and height of the board outside the loops and then - see if hundrets of equal checks are really a problem. I would think not even on a 486DX2 they would.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an arithmetic approach to loop-through with just 1 loop.

```
public static bool CheckShipSunk(string[,] board, string ship){
    int rows = board.GetLength(0);
    int cols = board.GetLength(1);
    for (int i = 0; i < rows * cols; i++) {
        int row = i / cols;
        int col = i % cols;
        if (board[row, col] == ship)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

But I am with Nysand on just caching and storing that information in cells. The above code although might work, is not recommended as it is still not as efficient

Comment: Yeah i'll probably go with their method, seems much more efficient than iterating through the loop at all, thanks for the help though all <3

Comment: How would 1 loop actually help over two loops? you are still looping over the same number of cells. And you have added some fairly expensive division and remainder operations.

Comment: @JonasH Each loop adds a level of nested function calls, which have a certain amount of overhead in terms of processing time and memory usage. By combining multiple loops into a single loop, you reduce the number of nested function calls and thus the overhead associated with them. Also, it can be more efficient because it uses a single counter variable `i` to keep track of the current position in the array, instead of using two separate counter variables `i`, and `j` as in the case of nested loops.

Comment: @voidops.com what? No! Simple loops should be compiled to a conditional jump. It should not involve any function calls at all. Sure, nested branches will make it slightly more difficult for the branch predictor, but modern CPUs should handle two nested loops with ease. And using multiple variables should have no overhead unless you are so registry starved you are doing *a loot* of stack access.

Comment: @JonasH I do acknowledge your concerns about using division here, the extra counter aside. The overhead of these operations is generally _outweighed_ by the reduced overhead of the single loop and the improved `cache locality` over nested functions. However, modern compilers should be able to optimize both of these algorithms in any case; or so we assume. I agree with you it might not matter with modern CPUs, especially when working with mature compilers like that of C++. Well, this question is about C#. In any case, I don't recommend either algorithm for that specific use case.

Comment: But what overhead? And more importantly, is a single loop actually faster? Granted, not calling `GetLength` for each iteration does help a great deal, but if you fix this the double loop is almost twice as fast when I test it.

Answer (score 1):

> this is very inefficient when checking hundreds of elements 5 times over

Have you done any profiling? Computers are *fast* even your old college computers. Checking hundreds of elements should take *microseconds*. From [Donald Knuths famous quote](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

> There is no doubt that the grail of efficiency leads to abuse. Programmers waste enormous amounts of time thinking about, or worrying about, the speed of noncritical parts of their programs, and these attempts at efficiency actually have a strong negative impact when debugging and maintenance are considered. We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil.

So if you feel your program is slow I would recommend to start with profiling. If you are in university this might be a very valuable skill to learn.

There are also better algorithms/datastructures that could be employed. I would for example expect each ship to know what locations they are at, and various other information, like if it is sunk at all. Selecting appropriate data structures are also a very important skill to learn, but a difficult one. Also, try to not get stuck in analysis-paralysis, a terrible inefficient ugly working solution is still better than the most beautiful code that does not work.

However, a very easy thing to fix is moving `.GetLength` out of the loop. This is a very slow call, and only doing this once should make your loop a several times faster for almost no effort. You might also consider replacing the strings with some other identifier, like an int.

Comment: By college, I mean it in the UK sense, which is before university level, and I've only just started learning c# so I've still got a lot to learn, i understand that it is still very fast, but I'd like to make my code as efficient as possible, even if it means saving a few microseconds, as it is just a good habit to get into.

Comment: @PrestonJ The problem is that you probably do not yet fully understand what efficiency means. There are whole courses at university about algorithmic efficiency. And it is often very difficult to guess if one solution is more efficient than another, even for very experienced developers. In some cases the "stupidly inefficient" solution is the better one in specific circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

Willy-Nilly you have to scan either the entire array or up to the first ship.

You can *simplify* the code by *quering* the array with help of *Linq*, but not increase performance which has `O(length * width)` time complexity.

```
using System.Linq;

...

// No explicit loops, juts a query (.net will loop for you) 
public static bool CheckShipSunk(string[,] board, string ship) => board is null
  ? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(board))
  : board.AsEnumerable().Any(item => item == ship);
```

If you are looking for *performance* (say, you have a really *huge* array, many ships to test etc.), I suggest changing the *data structure*: `Dictionary<string, (int row, int col)>`
instead of the `string[,]` array:

```
Dictionary<string, (int row, int col)> sunkShips = 
  new Dictionary<string, (int row, int col)>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
    { "Yamato",          (15, 46) },
    { "Bismark",         (11, 98) },
    { "Prince Of Wales", (23, 55) },
  };
```

and then get it as easy as

```
public static bool CheckShipSunk(IDictionary<string, (int row, int col)> sunkShips, 
                                 string ship) =>
  sunkShips?.Keys?.Contains(ship) ?? false;
```

Note that time complexity is `O(1)` which means it doesn't depend on board length and width